# Asignar Cursor a List

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

¿Cómo puedo asignar los resultados de un `cursor` a una `List` utilizando `SQL Server`y `Visual Studio`?

El cursor está en un procedimiento almacenado, el cual debe ser llamado desde el Controlador:

Procedimiento Almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Lista_municipios
@MunicipiosCursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @MunicipiosCursor = CURSOR
FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
select m.id_municipio,
       m.ca_municipio
  from Municipio m
OPEN @MunicipiosCursor;
```

Controlador

```
private InvestigacionEntities db = new InvestigacionEntities();

// GET api/Municipios
public IEnumerable<Municipio> GetMunicipios()
{
   //var test = db.Lista_municipios;
   return db.Lista_municipios.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se requiere ningún cursor para un simple `SELECT`, no hace falta, simplemente sería:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Lista_municipios
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select m.id_municipio,
       m.ca_municipio
  from Municipio m
```

No sé cómo estás mapeando, con Entity Framework si usas `Code First` o un `edmx`

[Stored Procedure in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

En el artículo plantea justamente lo que menciono del `Procedure`

Comment: gracias @Leandro Tuttini, pero el punto particular es asignarle ese resultado a una Lista...?

Comment: si pero estas usando entity framework, por lo que el cursor no aplica, puedes retornar la lista si el procedure realiza directo el SELECT